# Get information about a menu item

Tags: 8, routes

In Drupal 8, you can use system blocks to show menus starting from different levels. For example:

```
Menu item 1 (level1)
--- Menu Item 2 (level2)
--- Menu Item 3 (level2)

Menu item 4 (level1)
--- Menu Item 5 (level2)
--- Menu Item 6 (level2)
```

When user is on a page linked by menu item 2 I want to have a block showing the following:

```
Menu item 1 
    --- Menu Item 2
    --- Menu Item 3
```

What the main system block offers is the following result:

```
    --- Menu Item 2
    --- Menu Item 3
```

You see? I need the parent menu item of these menu items as well.

What I did so far is to define a custom block in my module:

```
class MainMenuBlockSecondLevel extends BlockBase {

  public function build() {
    $menu_name = 'main';
    $menu_tree = \Drupal::menuTree();
    $parameters = $menu_tree->getCurrentRouteMenuTreeParameters($menu_name);
    $parameters->setMinDepth(2);

    $tree = $menu_tree->load($menu_name, $parameters);
    $manipulators = array(
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:checkAccess'),
      array('callable' => 'menu.default_tree_manipulators:generateIndexAndSort'),
    );
    $tree = $menu_tree->transform($tree, $manipulators);

    $parents = $parameters->expandedParents;  // menu_link_content:dd7b39a6-c4c8-48dd-a1cf-92a755087c29


    $build['parent']['#markup'] = '<div class="parent-menuitem">Parent</div>';
    $build['menu'] = $menu_tree->build($tree);
    return $build;
  }
}
```

With the $parents variable I get an array like that:

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => menu_link_content:dd7b39a6-c4c8-48dd-a1cf-92a755087c29
)
```

Here it stops for me now. What is menu_link_content:dd7b39a6-c4c8-48dd-a1cf-92a755087c29 and how can I get the needed information like menu item title and path out of it?

Answer (score 3):

[`MenuTreeParameters::$expandedParents`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21lib%21Drupal%21Core%21Menu%21MenuTreeParameters.php/property/MenuTreeParameters%3A%3AexpandedParents/8.2.x) are a list of menu tree ids (a composite key of the menu bundle and the menu content UUID). You can see its data in the `menu_tree`, `menu_link_content`, `menu_link_content_data`, database tables.

If you need to programmatically invoke the menu item for reference, you can load it via Drupal's entity manager:

```
// Load each menu content item per UUID
foreach ($parents as $menu_uuid) {
  $menu_content = current(\Drupal::entityManager()->getStorage('menu_link_content')->loadByProperties(array('uuid' => $menu_uuid)));
  // @TODO: Reference menu content properties for data
  // (e.g. $menu_content->get('title')->value / $menu_content->get('link')
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this information - I will go deeper into all this stuff with this information. My first question: as the value of each key in my $parents array as a composite of bundle and UUID is there a helper function to get just the UUID of such a construction? I used '$uuid = substr($parents[2], 18)' to get just the UUID part. Additionally $parents array has many items - how can I get just the direct parent of the current menu item?

Comment: Newer versions of Drupal use entityTypeManager() instead of entityManager().